# how to clear result in racket?

Tags: scheme, racket

here is my code

```
#lang racket
(define a '())
(define (add l)
  (set! a (cons (car l) a)))
```

here is the result

```
> (add '(1))
> a
'(1)
> (add '(2))
> a
'(2 1)
```

the problem is that i want the (add '(2)) only shows (2) instead of (2 1), i don't want the previous result.
i want the result like this:

```
> (add '(1))
> a
'(1)
> (add '(2))
> a
'(2)
> (add '(3))
'(3)
```

can someone help me? thx!

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
(define (add l)
  (set! a (cons (car l) a)))
```

Clearly alters the binding of `a` to a new list formed from a new element from `l` and the original `a`. That's what the `cons` part do. Even It's name `add` reflects that. You seem to want something else, like:

```
(define (replace-a x)
  (set! a x))

(replace-a '(1))
a ; ==> (1)

(replace-a '(2))
a ; ==> (2)

(replace-a '(3))
a ; ==> (3)
```

If you just want to reset `a` to start over, you use `set` as well and put it where you want it reset:

```
(set! a '()) ; set a to the empty list (null)
```

Comment: sorry , what i mean is my (define a '()) is storing the result, and i want it to clear the result before running next (define (add l))

Comment: can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: @FrankYang I've updated my answer. Basically you use `set!` there too. Remember, altering globals is not very Scheme like but it happens.